# Mypy error when returning a generator expression

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function like this:

```
def foo(some_list: List[Any]) -> Generator[Any, None, None]:
    return (element for element in some_list)
```

According to the documentation for [`typing.Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) this should be one of several correct ways to type hint this functions return value. Yet mypy complains that it got an `Iterator[Any]` as the return value:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Iterator[Any]", expected "Generator[Any, None, None]")
```

Is this a bug in mypy or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: I think this might be a bug -- the issue appears to be that mypy is inferring the type of your generator comprehension as `Iterator[Any]` (which I agree seems wrong). This later causes issues because `Iterator[Any]` is not a valid subtype of `Generator[Any, None, None]` -- it's the other way around, in fact. I would try filing a bug report on the mypy issue tracker?

Comment: Ok, done: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5020